# Formula for $n^{th}$ derivative of $1/(x^2 +1)$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, induction

I am completely done with this problem. I transformed $x^2+1$ to $(x+i)(x-i)$, also used standard form of $n^{th}$ derivative of $\arctan(x)$, again gone negative binomial expansion but nothing is working. If anyone can make it I will be very glad. The question is:

> Show that the $n^{th}$ derivative of $1/(x^2+1)$ is equal to 
>   $$
> \frac{(-1)^n \cdot n!}{(x^2+1)^{n+1}} \cdot \left[(n+1)x^n - \,{}^{n+1}C_3 \,x^{n-2} +\,{}^{n+1}C_5\,x^{n-4} - \cdots \right]
> $$

Comment: I have edited your question to add some clarity. Please check that the edits are in line with the original question you wanted to ask.

Comment: What is $1C3$ supposed to mean? The binomial coefficient?

Comment: Could you clarify what $1C3$ and $1C5$ mean? Have you tried using induction for this problem?

Comment: Read "$n+1$ choose 3" etc. Could be meant as ${}^{n+1}C_3$. Usually written as $\binom{n+1}{3}$, `$\binom{n+1}{3}$`.

Comment: I really appreciate your concern dude

Comment: I don't know bro I am struck with this problem for past two months  I have give it a try by induction but hey result remains the same the given statement is not even true for n=2 . I don't know my this textbook question even has any sence or not . Give it a try if you can give time to this . And at last thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The partial fraction expansion is
$$f(x)=\frac1{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac1{x-i}-\frac1{x+i}\right).$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
f^{(n)}(x)&=(-1)^n\frac{n!}{2i}
\left(\frac1{(x-i)^{n+1}}-\frac1{(x+i)^{n+1}}\right)\\
&=(-1)^n\frac{n!}{2i(x^2+1)^{n+1}}
\left((x+i)^{n+1}-(x-i)^{n+1}\right)
\end{align}
and you get your formula by expanding the $(x\pm i)^{n+1}$
via the Binomial Theorem.